# Google maps intermittently loads without styles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map that loads without styles maybe 1 out of 30 refreshes and I think it's the way / order in which I'm loading the map json and the map data. I'm not quite sure the best way to do this so the styles are always there. I don't think this requires any async functions but not sure.

```
import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclusterer';

const currentPage = $('body').attr('id');
const hasMap = currentPage === 'homePage' || currentPage === 'venuesPage';

let infoArr = [];
let infowindow;
let latLng;
let mapStyles;
let marker;
let markerAddress;
let markerCluster;
let markerCount = -1;
let markerIcon;
let markerInfo;
let markers = [];
let zoomFactor = 4;

$.get('../../data/mapStyles.json').done(data => {
  mapStyles = data;
});

$.get('/data/venues.json').done((data) => {
  if (hasMap) { // does this need to be hasMap && mapStyles?
    initializeMap(data);
  }
});
let mcOptions = {
  gridSize: 40,
  maxZoom: 16,
  zoomOnClick: true,
  minimumClusterSize: 2,
  styles: [
    {
      height: 53,
      url: '/img/meta/m1.png',
      width: 53,
    },
    {
      height: 56,
      url: '/img/meta/m2.png',
      width: 56,
    },
    {
      height: 66,
      url: '/img/meta/m3.png',
      width: 66,
    },
    {
      height: 78,
      url: '/img/meta/m4.png',
      width: 78,
    },
    {
      height: 90,
      url: '/img/meta/m5.png',
      width: 90,
    },
  ],
};

function initializeMap(data) {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    zoomFactor = 3;
  }
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), {
    zoom: zoomFactor,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0, -102.0),
    styles: mapStyles,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  });

  markerIcon = '/img/svgs/icon_map_marker_venue.svg';

  data.forEach((venue) => {
    let {
      lat,
      long,
      name,
      streetAddress,
      city,
      state,
      slug,
    } = venue;

    if (lat !== '') {
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        icon: markerIcon,
      });
      markerAddress = `${streetAddress}<br>${city},&nbsp;${state}`;
      markerInfo = `<a class="map-marker" href="/venues/venue-detail/index.php?${slug}"><h5>${name}</h5>${markerAddress}</a>`;
      markers.push(marker);
      infoArr.push(markerInfo);
      markerCount += 1;
    }

    google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.isOpen = function () {
      let map = this.getMap();
      return (map !== null && typeof map !== 'undefined');
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, markerCount) {
      return function () {
        if (!infowindow.isOpen()) {
          infowindow.setContent(infoArr[markerCount]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          infowindow.close();
        }
      };
    }(marker, markerCount)));
  });
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your `$.get` to define `mapStyles` should be done synchronously, so that its value is known before execution continues.

Comment: Thanks, I used jQuery `$.when()` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I did the the json gets like this and it works:

```
$.when($.get('../../data/mapStyles.json').done(styleData => {
  mapStyles = styleData;
}), $.get('/data/venues.json').done(vData => {
  venueData = vData;
})).then(() => {
  initialize(venueData);
});
```